# replace() in MongoDB MapReduce map function

Tags: php, mongodb, mapreduce

I am trying to do a pattern match and replace in my MongoDB mapReduce.  I am mapreducing the sources of tweets in the db.  And getting repeating results like

```
1 - web has 38867
2 - <a href="http://www.tweetdeck.com" rel="nofollow">TweetDeck</a> has 23873
3 - <a href="http://www.hootsuite.com" rel="nofollow">HootSuite</a> has 10696
4 - <a href="http://twitterfeed.com" rel="nofollow">twitterfeed</a> has 9562
5 - <a href="http://twitter.com/#!/download/iphone" rel="nofollow">Twitter for iPhone</a> has 6818
6 - <a href="http://www.echofon.com/" rel="nofollow">Echofon</a> has 5869
7 - <a href="http://www.tweetdeck.com/" rel="nofollow">TweetDeck</a> has 5497
```

The only difference between #2 and #7 is the ".com/" vs ".com" in the href.  I'd like to do a pattern match in my map function, but I am getting compile errors.  I may be getting lost in the layers of translation.

PHP ==> Mongo ==> javascript.

Here is my code block

```
$map = 'function() {
            if (!this.source) {
                return;
            }
            s = this.source;
            s = s.replace(/\/\"/i,"/"");

            emit(s,1);
        }';

$reduce = "function(previous, current) {
    var count = 0;
    for (index in current) {
        count += current[index];
    }
    return count;
}";

$mapFunc = new MongoCode($map);
$reduceFunc = new MongoCode($reduce);
$collectionOutName = 'mrTweetSource';
$mr = $db->command(array(
    'mapreduce' => 'tweet',
    'map' => $mapFunc,
    'reduce' => $reduceFunc,
    'out'=>$collectionOutName));
```

the result is

```
(
    [assertion] => couldn't compile code for: _map
    [assertionCode] => 13598
    [errmsg] => db assertion failure
    [ok] => 0
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically, the easiest way to test this is simply to run the M/R from the shell. This will help with compilation b/c the shell can identify bad syntax.

If I use my "human compilation" skills, the following looks wrong.

```
s = s.replace(/\/\"/i,"/"");
```

You are escaping `/"` and replacing it with `/` ? Take a look at `"/""`, that seems to be one too many double quotes.